# python.h not found

Tags: python, gcc

I got an installation script that calls gcc and gcc tries to compile a .c file that includes a header that does not exist on my system (ubuntu) .

```
#include "Python.h"
```

I have both python 2.x and python 3.x installed but running a

```
sudo find / -name "Python.h"
```

gives back no results.
I suspect that it might not be bundled with python binaries.
Did anyone have to solve something similar to this?Thank you.

Comment: Just to follow up on this. The python-dev packages aims for your default python installation while python3.2-dev for your python3.2 installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Python.h` is part of the source code for python. You will need `python-dev` to get the headers installed correctly. Just run `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

If you need the development files for Python 3, use `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` instead.

Comment: Yes, python-dev added /usr/lib/python2.7/Python.h . Thanks for the advice.